# SQL - applying two different conditions after group by to select rows from sql table

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, numpy

I am willing to filter the rows based on the group of **client id, date**

So in the group if the latest status as per **update date** = 'CO' then earliest rows as per update date and if the latest status in ('NonPay','VD','Active') then the latest row as per update date.

Table look like: **table1**

| rownum | clientid | date | status | updateDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | 2021-02-01 | CO | 2021-02-01 |
| 2 | 1234 | 2021-02-01 | CO | 2021-01-01 |
| 3 | 1234 | 2021-02-01 | NonPay | 2020-12-01 |
| 4 | 1234 | 2021-02-03 | Active | 2021-11-01 |
| 5 | 1234 | 2021-02-03 | CO | 2021-10-01 |
| 6 | 1234 | 2021-02-03 | CO | 2021-09-01 |
| 7 | 1234 | 2021-02-04 | CO | 2021-08-01 |
| 8 | 1234 | 2021-02-04 | VD | 2021-07-01 |
| 9 | 4567 | 2019-06-01 | Active | 2020-12-28 |
| 10 | 4567 | 2019-06-01 | CO | 2020-12-20 |
| 11 | 4567 | 2019-06-01 | NonPay | 2020-12-10 |
| 12 | 4567 | 2019-05-03 | VD | 2020-12-01 |
| 13 | 4567 | 2019-05-03 | Active | 2020-11-01 |
| 14 | 4567 | 2019-05-03 | CO | 2020-10-01 |
| 15 | 4567 | 2019-05-03 | NP | 2020-09-01 |
| 16 | 4567 | 2019-04-04 | CO | 2020-08-01 |
| 17 | 4567 | 2019-04-04 | VD | 2020-07-01 |

So the expected result would look like :

| rownum | clientid | date | status | updateDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1234 | 2021-02-01 | NonPay | 2020-12-01 |
| 4 | 1234 | 2021-02-03 | Active | 2021-11-01 |
| 8 | 1234 | 2021-02-04 | VD | 2021-07-01 |
| 9 | 4567 | 2019-06-01 | Active | 2020-02-01 |
| 12 | 4567 | 2019-05-03 | VD | 2020-12-01 |
| 17 | 4567 | 2019-04-04 | VD | 2020-07-01 |

I tried :

```
select *,
       case when rank_date=1 and status=!='Active' 
            then max(rank_date)
            else min(rank_date) end as selected_rank_date 
from (select *, 
             rank() over(partition by clientid, date 
                         order     by updateDate desc) as rank_date 
      from table1)
```

And on top of this I will compare the rank_date and selected_rank_date, wherever they are equal, I will select those rows.
But unfortunately I am not able to figure out the first query itself, trying since a week.

If there's python way of doing then it should be optimized as the table size is huge approx. to 1 billion records.

Comment: This is valid question, but still wanted to know if I have missed anything, or broke any law of stackoverflow. would correct from next time.

Comment: I may have a solution, but your output values are wrong according to your request: in the output there should be `rownum` 11 in place of `rownum` 9, as long as the biggest `updateDate` in range `rownum` 9-11 is 11 and it has `NonPay` status, for which you want to latest `updateDate`, corresponding to `rownum` 11. Is my reasoning correct? @Abhishek

Comment: *And on top of this I will compare the rank_date and selected_rank_date, wherever they are equal* - do you require all passages or it's just fine for you to have when rank_date = selected_rank_date?

Comment: @lemon - you pointed out right, I have corrected the same.

Comment: Can you show the output table related to your sentence: *I will compare the rank_date and selected_rank_date, wherever they are equal, I will select those rows* @Abhishek

Comment: I have mentioned the rank_date in the sql query but still figuring selected_rank_date then only solution would complete. - @lemon

Answer (score 1):

```
#Import the csv in df and try with below code...
grp = df.groupby(['clientid', 'date'], axis=0)
li = []
for i, j in grp:
    j.sort_values(by=['updateDate'], ascending = True)
    fil = j['status'] != 'CO'
    j = j.loc[fil, :].reset_index(drop=True)
    li.append(j.loc[0,:])
pd.DataFrame(li)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Valid python solution

Answer (score 1):

One approach to solve your problem in MySQL is the following:

- Step 1: get the first and the last `updateDate` for each partition `(client_id, date)`
- Step 2: get the last `updateDate` for the group `('NonPay','VD','Active')`
- Step 3: get the first `updateDate` for the group `('CO')`
- Step 4: do a union of the rows for the two groups

---

**Step 1**: you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

- ascendently over `updateDate` to find first date of the partition where this value equals 1
- descendently over `updateDate` to find last date of the partition where this value equals 1

```
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY clientid, date
                         ORDER     BY updateDate     ) AS firstUpdateDate,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY clientid, date
                         ORDER     BY updateDate DESC) AS lastUpdateDate
FROM tab
```

---

**Step 2**: when you have one of the statuses `('NonPay','VD','Active')` in the last date, you require to retrieve the last date itself, hence getting the corresponding rows means effectively to retrieve the last rows (`lastUpdateDate = 1`) where the status is one of the previously cited ones.

```
SELECT rd.rownum, 
       rd.clientid, 
       rd.date, 
       rd.status, 
       rd.updateDate
FROM ranked_dates rd
WHERE rd.lastUpdateDate = 1
  AND rd.status IN ('NonPay', 'VD', 'Active')
```

---

**Step 3**: when you have one status `'CO'` in the last date, you require to retrieve the first date, or in other words, from all the first dates that we have, we don't want those rows whose combination of (`clientid`, `date`) has already been captured from the Step 2. You can do this with an left join where the left table values are null (those values for which you don't have correspondence in the table generated by Step 2).

```
SELECT rd.rownum, 
       rd.clientid, 
       rd.date, 
       rd.status, 
       rd.updateDate
FROM       ranked_dates rd
LEFT JOIN np_vd_active_status s 
       ON rd.clientid = s.clientid
      AND rd.date = s.date
WHERE rd.firstUpdateDate = 1
  AND s.rownum IS NULL
```

---

**Step 4**: just apply a union between Step 2 result and Step 3 result. If you want to make some ordering on the `rownum` field, you can do that easily with an `ORDER BY` statement.

---

**Final Query**:

```
WITH ranked_dates AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY clientid, date
                             ORDER     BY updateDate     ) AS firstUpdateDate,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY clientid, date
                             ORDER     BY updateDate DESC) AS lastUpdateDate
    FROM tab  
), np_vd_active_status AS (
    SELECT rd.rownum, 
           rd.clientid, 
           rd.date, 
           rd.status, 
           rd.updateDate
    FROM ranked_dates rd
    WHERE rd.lastUpdateDate = 1
      AND rd.status IN ('NonPay', 'VD', 'Active')
)
SELECT rd.rownum, 
       rd.clientid, 
       rd.date, 
       rd.status, 
       rd.updateDate
FROM       ranked_dates rd
LEFT JOIN np_vd_active_status s 
       ON rd.clientid = s.clientid
      AND rd.date = s.date
WHERE rd.firstUpdateDate = 1
  AND s.rownum IS NULL

UNION

SELECT * 
FROM np_vd_active_status
```

Try it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3VFb6YNQ7Tn1J1A3BUhcsc/0).

Comment: if you want to play with rank positions, then you should play in the `WHERE` clauses of this query, when I do `firstUpdateDate = 1` or `lastUpdateDate = 1`

Comment: Thank @lemon Yes this working, But execution is failing for large table. Is there a way to optimize for larger tables, do share

Comment: After having gone through several revisions of this code, for the moment this is my most-efficient general solution I can think of. If I can come up with something more efficient, I'll let you know. @Abhishek

Comment: For a moment your solution saved me, thank you so much @lemon